# cannot override mixin behavior after it's used in a class definition

Tags: javascript, extjs, mixins

I need to override some member functions added by a [mixin](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.Mixin.html) from a 3rd-party library. The problem is: the mixin is used in multiple 3rd-party class definitions immediately, in the same script file where the mixin is defined. And I can only insert custom code before or after this script, but not in between. If I call `override` afterwards, then already defined classes don't obtain my function in the call chain.

```
// library script BEGIN
Ext.define('Foo.bar.Base', {
});


Ext.define('Foo.bar.Util', {
  newmember: function() {
    console.log('newmember');
  }
});


Ext.define('Foo.bar.Derived', {
   extend: 'Foo.bar.Base',

   mixins: {
       fooutil: 'Foo.bar.Util'
   }
});

// library script END

Foo.bar.Util.override({
   newmember: function () {
       console.log('newmember2');
       this.callParent();
   }
});


var obj = new Foo.bar.Derived();

obj.newmember();
```

Actual Output:

```
newmember
```

Desired Output:

```
newmember2
newmember
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override before defining a class using a mixin. This can be done using [override](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-override) as a property when defining:

```
Ext.define('Foo.bar.UtilOverride',{
   override: 'Foo.bar.Util',
   newmember: function () {
       console.log('newmember2');
       this.callParent();
   }
});

// library script BEGIN
Ext.define('Foo.bar.Base', {
});


Ext.define('Foo.bar.Util', {
  newmember: function() {
    console.log('newmember');
  }
});


Ext.define('Foo.bar.Derived', {
   extend: 'Foo.bar.Base',

   mixins: {
       fooutil: 'Foo.bar.Util'
   }
});

// library script END



var obj = new Foo.bar.Derived();

obj.newmember();
```